# Angular @Component using `require(...)` in template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

In VSCode with an Angular component declared as so

```
@Component({
    selector: 'thing',
    template: require('./thing.html'),
})
```

We'll get an IDE error as follows

```
template must be a string
  Value could not be determined statically.(-991010)
user-permission-groups-list.component.ts(9, 15): Unable to evaluate an invalid expression.
```

However in another IDE, WebStorm, our folks do not get this same error.

Is there an extension, setting, and/or other configuration us VSCode folks are missing that do not flag `require(..)` use like that as a problem?

Comment: don't post images of text, very hard to search for the message

Comment: @rioV8 Swapped.

Comment: Why are you using require there?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Not mine, but navigating around I noticed it, and wondered why other folks were not getting the same error/issue.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @ArmandoPeña Never found the fix. One thing you can do is do the require up top with your imports then just remove the require() call in the template itself, but for us it broke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23553.

Issue was closed due to insufficient votes.